# Avoid exit mode when a partition is not mounted

Tags: fstab, fsck, runlevel

Everytime a HDD partition is not mounted with /etc/fstab due to errors, system halts on emergency mode.
I want my server auto check itself using fsck on emergency mode or avoid the emergency mode when is not properly mounted and auto check itself later. Manual check is not possible for my when I'm far from the server.

Do you know how can I fix it? Thanks

Update: Solution is to add "nofail" option in the /etc/fstab mount line. Thanks to vanadium

Comment: Perhaps the `nofail` mount option serves this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure systemd to ignore fstab drive mount failures?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638985/how-to-configure-systemd-to-ignore-fstab-drive-mount-failures)

Comment: Yes, It is a better approach to my needs. Thanks